# What/Which beatmaps are bundled with osu?

Tags: osu

So, when you open osu! for the first time, it downloads a few beatmaps directly via osu!direct (regardless of being a supporter or not) that serves as bundled beatmaps ("pre-installed" with the game).

I'm currently away from a computer, so I cannot find out myself. **Which/what beatmaps does osu! download that makes up the group of "bundled" beatmaps?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beatmaps that are included when you download Osu! for the first time are the following:

- [osu! tutorial - Peter Lambert](https://osu.ppy.sh/s/3756)
- [My Love - Kuba Oms](https://osu.ppy.sh/s/163112)
- [Tear Rain - cYsmix feat Emmy](https://osu.ppy.sh/s/140662)
- [Lost - Chasers](https://osu.ppy.sh/s/151878)
- [Flaklypa - Rameses B](https://osu.ppy.sh/s/190390)
- [Liquid (Paul Rosenthal Remix) - Rostik](https://osu.ppy.sh/s/123593)
- [Renatus - Soleily](https://osu.ppy.sh/s/241526)
- [the light - raja](https://osu.ppy.sh/b/671412)

Comment: Eh? I thought there were more than that?

Comment: Back in my time (~2011) there was only tutorial :) Never knew that this was changed since.

Comment: @aytimothy Sorry for that. Redownloaded it to check and got a problem when downloading the bundles. The list is complete now. :)

Answer (score 3):

As of 23rd of October 2019, the bundled beatmaps are now **random**, as stated from the [changelog page](https://osu.ppy.sh/home/changelog/stable40/20191023.4):

> Bundled beatmaps are now selected at random each install, chosen from a large library of Featured Artist creations!

---

On the next update (released on 30rd of October 2019) it was stated that the beatmaps now have a weekly rotation, meaning that you'll get a different set of maps on a weekly basis.

Direct quotation from the [changelog page](https://osu.ppy.sh/home/changelog/stable40/20191031):

> Change bundled beatmap seed to be a weekly rotation

---

Installing older versions of osu! will have the old set of songs to be downloaded, as stated on this [answer in this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/308882/235585).

Answer (score 1):

There were also some additional maps from cYsmix included:

- [Classical Pursuit - cYsmix](https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/488238#osu/1040942)
- [Fright March - cYsmix](https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/486142#osu/1038400)
- [Moonlight Sonata - cYsmix](https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/486535#osu/1037478)
- [(another version of Moonlight Sonata)](https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/489524#osu/1043412)

Answer (score 0):

Since version 20191023.4 those two songs are downloaded each time:

```
1011011 nekodex - new beginnings
1388906 Raphlesia & BilliumMoto - My Love
```

On top of that, 17 songs from the following library get randomly chosen per week:

```
682286 Yuyoyuppe - Emerald Galaxy
682287 baker - For a Dead Girl+
682289 Hige Driver - I Wanna Feel Your Love (feat. shully)
682290 Hige Driver - Miracle Sugite Yabai (feat. shully)
682416 Hige Driver - Palette
682595 baker - Kimi ga Kimi ga -vocanico remix-
716211 yuki. - Spring Signal
716213 dark cat - BUBBLE TEA (feat. juu & cinders)
716215 LukHash - CLONED
716219 IAHN - Snowdrop
716249 *namirin - Senaka Awase no Kuukyo (with Kakichoco)
716390 sakuraburst - SHA
716441 Fractal Dreamers - Paradigm Shift
729808 Thaehan - Leprechaun
751771 Cranky - Hanaarashi
751772 Cranky - Ran
751773 Cranky - Feline, the White...
751774 Function Phantom - Variable
751779 Rin - Daishibyo set 14 ~ Sado no Futatsuiwa
751782 Fractal Dreamers - Fata Morgana
751785 Cranky - Chandelier - King
751846 Fractal Dreamers - Celestial Horizon
751866 Rin - Moriya set 08 ReEdit ~ Youkai no Yama
751894 Fractal Dreamers - Blue Haven
751896 Cranky - Rave 2 Rave
751932 Cranky - La fuite des jours
751972 Cranky - CHASER
779173 Thaehan - Superpower
780932 VINXIS - A Centralized View
785572 S3RL - I'll See You Again (feat. Chi Chi)
785650 yuki. feat. setsunan - Hello! World
785677 Dictate - Militant
785731 S3RL - Catchit (Radio Edit)
785774 LukHash - GLITCH
786498 Trial & Error - Tokoyami no keiyaku KEGARETA-SHOUJO feat. GUMI
789374 Pulse - LP
789528 James Portland - Sky
789529 Lexurus - Gravity
789544 Andromedik - Invasion
789905 Gourski x Himmes - Silence
791667 cYsmix - Babaroque (Short Ver.)
791798 cYsmix - Behind the Walls
791845 cYsmix - Little Knight
792241 cYsmix - Eden
792396 cYsmix - The Ballad of a Mindless Girl
795432 Phonetic - Journey
831322 DJ'TEKINA//SOMETHING - Hidamari no Uta
847764 Cranky - Crocus
847776 Culprate & Joe Ford - Gaucho
847812 J. Pachelbel - Canon (Cranky Remix)
847900 Cranky - Time Alter
847930 LukHash - 8BIT FAIRY TALE
848003 Culprate - Aurora
848068 nanobii - popsicle beach
848090 Trial & Error - DAI*TAN SENSATION feat. Nanahira, Mii, Aitsuki Nakuru (Short Ver.)
848259 Culprate & Skorpion - Jester
848976 Dictate - Treason
851543 Culprate - Florn
864748 Thaehan - Angry Birds Epic (Remix)
873667 OISHII - ONIGIRI FREEWAY
876227 Culprate, Keota & Sophie Meiers - Mechanic Heartbeat
880487 cYsmix - Peer Gynt
883088 Wisp X - Somewhere I'd Rather Be
891333 HyuN - White Aura
891334 HyuN - Wild Card
891337 HyuN feat. LyuU - Cross Over
891338 HyuN & Ritoru - Apocalypse in Love
891339 HyuN feat. Ato - Asu wa Ame ga Yamukara
891345 HyuN - Infinity Heaven
891348 HyuN - Guitian
891356 HyuN - Legend of Genesis
891366 HyuN - Illusion of Inflict
891417 HyuN feat. Yu-A - My life is for you
891441 HyuN - You'Re aRleAdY dEAd
891632 HyuN feat. YURI - Disorder
891712 HyuN - Tokyo's Starlight
901091 *namirin - Ciel etoile
916990 *namirin - Koishiteiku Planet
929284 tieff - Sense of Nostalgia
933940 Ben Briggs - Yes (Maybe)
934415 Ben Briggs - Fearless Living
934627 Ben Briggs - New Game Plus
934666 Ben Briggs - Wave Island
936126 siromaru + cranky - conflict
940377 onumi - ARROGANCE
940597 tieff - Take Your Swimsuit
941085 tieff - Our Story
949297 tieff - Sunflower
952380 Ben Briggs - Why Are We Yelling
954272 *namirin - Kanzen Shouri*Esper Girl
955866 KIRA & Heartbreaker - B.B.F (feat. Hatsune Miku & Kagamine Rin)
961320 Kuba Oms - All In All
964553 The Flashbulb - You Take the World's Weight Away
965651 Fractal Dreamers - Ad Astra
966225 The Flashbulb - Passage D
966324 DJ'TEKINA//SOMETHING - Hidamari no Uta
972810 James Landino & Kabuki - Birdsong
972932 James Landino - Hide And Seek
977276 The Flashbulb - Mellann
981616 *namirin - Mizutamari Tobikoete (with Nanahira)
985788 Loki - Wizard's Tower
996628 OISHII - ONIGIRI FREEWAY
996898 HyuN - White Aura
1003554 yuki. - Nadeshiko Sensation
1014936 Thaehan - Bwa !
1019827 UNDEAD CORPORATION - Sad Dream
1020213 Creo - Idolize
1021450 Thaehan - Chiptune & Baroque
707824 Fractal Dreamers - Fortuna Redux
789553 Cranky - Ran
827822 Function Phantom - Neuronecia
847323 Nakanojojo - Bittersweet (feat. Kuishinboakachan a.k.a Kiato)
847433 Trial & Error - Tokoyami no keiyaku KEGARETA-SHOUJO feat. GUMI
847576 dark cat - hot chocolate
847957 Wisp X - Final Moments
876282 VINXIS - Greetings
876648 Thaehan - Angry Birds Epic (Remix)
877069 IAHN - Transform (Original Mix)
877496 Thaehan - Leprechaun
877935 Thaehan - Overpowered
878344 yuki. - Be Your Light
918446 VINXIS - Facade
918903 LukHash - Ghosts
919251 *namirin - Hitokoto no Kyori
919704 S3RL - I Will Pick You Up (feat. Tamika)
921535 SOOOO - Raven Haven
927206 *namirin - Kanzen Shouri*Esper Girl
927544 Camellia feat. Nanahira - Kansoku Eisei
930806 Nakanojojo - Pararara (feat. Amekoya)
931741 Camellia - Quaoar
935699 Rin - Mythic set ~ Heart-Stirring Urban Legends
935732 Thaehan - Yuujou
941145 Function Phantom - Euclid
942334 Dictate - Cauldron
946540 nanobii - astral blast
948844 Rin - Kishinjou set 01 ~ Mist Lake
949122 Wisp X - Petal
951618 Rin - Kishinjou set 02 ~ Mermaid from the Uncharted Land
957412 Rin - Lunatic set 16 ~ The Space Shrine Maiden Returns Home
961335 Thaehan - Insert Coin
965178 The Flashbulb - DIDJ PVC
966087 The Flashbulb - Creep
966277 The Flashbulb - Amen Iraq
966407 LukHash - ROOM 12
966451 The Flashbulb - Six Acid Strings
972301 BilliumMoto - four veiled stars
973173 nanobii - popsicle beach
973954 BilliumMoto - Rocky Buinne (Short Ver.)
975435 BilliumMoto - life flashes before weeb eyes
978759 L. V. Beethoven - Moonlight Sonata (Cranky Remix)
982559 BilliumMoto - HDHR
984361 The Flashbulb - Ninedump
1023681 Inferi - The Ruin of Mankind
1034358 ALEPH - The Evil Spirit
1037567 ALEPH - Scintillations
554256 Helblinde - When Time Sleeps
693123 yuki. - Nadeshiko Sensation
767009 OISHII - PIZZA PLAZA
767346 Thaehan - Bwa !
815162 VINXIS - Greetings
840964 cYsmix - Breeze
932657 Wisp X - Eventide
933700 onumi - CONFUSION PART ONE
933984 onumi - PERSONALITY
934785 onumi - FAKE
936545 onumi - REGRET PART ONE
943803 Fractal Dreamers - Everything for a Dream
943876 S3RL - I Will Pick You Up (feat. Tamika)
946773 Trial & Error - DREAMING COLOR (Short Ver.)
955808 Trial & Error - Tokoyami no keiyaku KEGARETA-SHOUJO feat. GUMI (Short Ver.)
957808 Fractal Dreamers - Module_410
957842 antiPLUR - One Life Left to Live
965730 The Flashbulb - Lawn Wake IV (Black)
966240 Creo - Challenger
968232 Rin - Lunatic set 15 ~ The Moon as Seen from the Shrine
972302 VINXIS - A Centralized View
972887 HyuN - Illusion of Inflict
1008600 LukHash - WHEN AN ANGEL DIES
1032103 LukHash - H8 U
943516 antiPLUR - Clockwork Spooks
946394 VINXIS - Three Times The Original Charm
966408 antiPLUR - One Life Left to Live
971561 antiPLUR - Runengon
983864 James Landino - Shiba Island
989512 BilliumMoto - 1xMISS
994104 James Landino - Reaction feat. Slyleaf
1003217 nekodex - circles!
1009907 James Landino & Kabuki - Birdsong
1015169 Thaehan - Insert Coin
```